# Netlogo: Ask directed link "my-in-turtle" and "my-out-turtle"

Tags: netlogo

I've been working in netlogo for some time, but there is one thing I can't really figure out. You can ask a turtle what its out- and in-links are, but is there a way to ask a link the equivalent using a simple construction of both-ends and/or other-end?

right now my code is

```
if one-of both-ends [firing = true] and one-of both-ends [time-not-fired = 1] [do-stuff]
```

but what I'd like to do is

```
if my-in-turtle [firing = true] and my-out-turtle [time-not-fired = 1] [do-stuff]
```

is there an easier/faster way than to iterate over all turtles with [firing = true] and asking all their links if the other end has [time-not-fired = 1] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
in-link-neighbors
```

It reports the set of turtles with links to the turtle calling it.

```
ask turtles with [firing]
 [
   ask in-link-neighbors with [time-not-fired = 1][do-stuff]
 ]
```

Now be cautious this code my ask some turtles to do stuff more than once. so put in safeguards.

I realized you want to ask links not turtles.

"My-in-turtle" (the source) is called `end1` "my-out-turtle"(the destination) is `end2` on directed breeds.

Comment: Thanks, but I see I still have to iterate over all turtles... Optimization is becoming an issue with hundreds of connected neurons. Still, this is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Yeah sorry. On directed breeds end1 is the source end2 is the destination. Maybe we could work something out with that? But then you are iterating over links

Comment: omg thanks! I completely overlooked the built in variables section in the dictionary. end1 and end2 is exactly what I was looking for! iterating over links is better because I can fit it inside an already existing loop with a strong "with [...]" selection, so is doesn't add much computation.